# How to load native JOGL .jnilib extensions on Mac OSX by exported app.jar?

Tags: java, macos, java-native-interface, jogl

The issue seems to be that on Mac OSX (as opposed to Windows), jogl.jar requires the native extensions be in a particular system path `/System/Library/Java/Extensions/` (as stated on: http://cs.gmu.edu/~jchen/graphics/jogl/notes/joglSetup.html).

However, I am distributing this app and there's no way I can ask my users to copy random .jnilib files into a system folder, especially when my users are relatively tech agnostic.

I then tried to create a Visualizer.command file with:

`java -Djava.library.path=./lib/opengl-natives/macosx/ -jar ./viz.jar`

And put the required libraries in the stated path, however that didn't work, either.

On Windows, merely having the native .dll in the same folder as the .jar file works, but I'm told that on unix systems (like Mac), this doesn't work as unix by default does not load libraries from the current working directory unless otherwise instructed.

EDIT:
Just as a reference, here's the Visualizer.bat file I have on Windows to do the same library loading:

`java -Djava.library.path=.\lib\opengl-natives\windows32 -jar parking-viz.jar`

Comment: Can't you create an installer that checks for the extensions/installs them?

Comment: SJuan76, this isn't necessary, Xerxes is right. There is nothing special to do. At first, jogl.jar no longer exists, it comes from JOGL 1 which isn't maintained, he should use JOGL 2 which is actively maintained. JOGL 2 stores all its native libraries into JARs, they just have to be in the same directories than JOGL & GlueGen JARs containing the classes (jogl-all.jar & gluegen-rt.jar) or in the worst case you can create a single fat JAR containing both your application and JOGL. Anyway, there is no Java library path to set and no native library to copy into a directory.

Comment: Moreover, the webpage quoted above is completely obsolete, it points to completely outdated JOGL JARs (JSR 231 beta 5, which is even older than JOGL 1). This extremely old version of JOGL has no chance to work on a modern Mac. Rather go to http://jogamp.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using JogAmp JOGL 2, the native extensions are no longer required to be in a particular system path, instead you only need to include jogl-all.jar and gluegen-rt.jar to your project. All the macos x specific native jars will be automatically found at runtime if they are located next to the jogl-all.jar and gluegen-rt.jar
http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE